# Please help me which word to Insert here

Tags: word-request

Context: A blind man is firing an automatic rifle. A man who's standing behind him turns the blind man, directing the _________ at the captor, who runs out of the room to escape the rain of bullets.

What would be the best choice of word here? Could "salvo" work?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some words that could work:

- gunfire
- firing
- sniping
- flak
- bombardment
- fusillade
- volley
- barrage
- rifle fire
- salvo
- cannonade

I would probably fill it in with: *"the fire or firing"* which, at least for me, should be the best choice. But your pick is just as correct as mine.